# How can I make a 3 partition system to 2 partition system?

Tags: windows-7, partitioning

I have now 4 partitions C, D, F and System reserved. For some unknown reason I can not merge two of my partitions viz. D and F. So what I want to do now is to delete those partitions and create a single partition D along with C. D will be used to keep my files. So how can I do that?

Comment: "For some unknown reason" - What did you use to do this - Disk Management or a 3rd party utility? Were there no errors displayed?

Answer (score 0):

Move everything from F to D; delete F; extend D to the space unallocated by F. If D hasn't enough space, then preferrably move to an external disk (if you have).

If it is not possible to move everything (and you do not have another disk), move some, then shrink F and extend D, and repeat until everything is moved (this may take a LONG time - AND DAMAGE DISK, SO BE VERY CAREFUL, try to borrow a disk from someone).

I suggest you use a live GParted disk, I feel more comfortable using a software outside my operating system to do this dirty job.

Comment: Shrinking and extending multiple times may bring some risk with it. I did the same a few years ago and after 5 times the drive died =/... Could be coincidence, but it is surely less healthy than deleting F at once and extend D.

Comment: @Mixxiphoid yes, it does do some very heavy operations on the disk and it is not very recommendable. As I didn't make assumptions that OP has a spare disk or external disk, that's the best I can say.